# Using Python, how do I get a binary serialization of my Google protobuf message?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I see the function SerializeAsString in the [protobuf Python documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class.html), but like this suggests, this gives me a string version of the binary data. Is there a way of serializing and parsing a binary array of protobuf data using Python?

We have a C++ application that stores the protobuf messages as binary data in a file. We'd like to read and write to the file using Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 2 (edit: end of life 2020) strings can hold binary data, therefore `SerializeAsString` returns binary data.

*Edit:* Surfacing from comments: "In Python 3, the `SerializeToString` method returns an instance of bytes"

Comment: It is 2019 - The above mentioned function may be now renamed to `SerializeToString` (I don't know whether it was indeed `SerializeAsString` when this was answered) 
Adding comments for the benefit of those come looking.

Comment: It is 2022 and this answer is specific to Python 2, which reached end of life in 2020. In Python 3, the `SerializeToString` method returns an instance of `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

`.serializeToString()`, despite its name, returns the `bytes` type, not the `str` type.

Part of what makes this confusing is that the method name remains unchanged, and they haven't updated the documentation; you just have to know that when they say "String" they mean `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that strings are the usual way to represent binary data in Python. What do you exactly want to do?

[Edit]

Have a look at the struct module: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythons Strings for getting proto buffers serialized data (doesn't matter how they ware crated - in Python, Java, C++ or any other language).

These is line from Pythons version of proto buffers tutorial:
`address_book.ParseFromString(f.read())`

Answer (score -1):

It not clear what you want to do:

1. Do something with the serialized form of an entire message (From the SerializeAsString method). Not sure what you'd want to do with this?
2. Store a byte string inside a protobuf message - just use the `bytes` type in the .proto file, and a byte string in python for the variable.