# How to use pika to send a file via rabbitmq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, sendfile, pika

I have looked through the tutorials on [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) and find it useful.

But I can't find a document telling how to send files via rabbitmq, using pika.

Code examples are preferred, and other libraries other than pika are acceptable.

Comment: What have you tried?  RabbitMQ supports binary.  Can you serialize to binary and then send?

Comment: @dtryon seems pika only accepts string as the parameter. I tried using pickle, but pickle can't serialize file object

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859438/using-python-how-do-i-get-a-binary-serialization-of-my-google-protobuf-message

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by using base64encode.

I build a json object - example:

```
data = {
filname = 'myfile.txt',
b64 = 'the base64 representation of the file'
}
```

Then, at the consumer side

base64decode :)

Answer (score -2):

You can send file name as a message and on consumer side you can setup passwordless scp to fetch file from remote machine hosting the file.